# Expression contains unexpanded parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Somehow I don't get how variadic template parameter packs are expanded. What's wrong with thie following code?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct print_one
{
    static void run(const T& t)
    {
        std::cout << t << ' ';
    }
};

template<typename... Args>
void print_all(Args&&... args)
{
    // the next line doesn't compile:
    print_one<Args>::run(std::forward<Args>(args))...;
}

int main()
{
    print_all(1.23, "foo");
}
```

Clang says, `Expression contains unexpanded parameter packs 'Args' and 'args'`. Why?

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question, just let it stand in the answer that provided it. Only do this if the answers gave you hints on how to solve this and didn't specify an exact solution. :)

Comment: Oh, ok. The only difference was `int dummy[] = {` ... `};` since my compiler doesn't support initializer lists.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that. Maybe edit it into ecatmur's answer? :) (aka change his first example from `int dummy[]{...}` to `int dummy[] = {...}`).

Comment: That edit is too short. I guess he has to do it himself.

Comment: Edited his answer. Btw, if you're using Clang, I recommend updating to the newest version or maybe even the trunk, it supports initializer lists.

Comment: Tnx. I use the Clang in the latest stable Xcode, because the editor of the current beta (developer preview 4) crashes all the time.

Comment: I see. The Clang delivered with Xcode is always pretty old, most of the time a full .x revision behind.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `...` has to go inside the function call parentheses:

```
print_one<Args>::run(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Obviously, that won't work for your function that takes only a single argument, so you need to  find a way to expand the calls into a function call or other allowed construct:

```
// constructing a dummy array via uniform initialization
// the extra 0 at the start is to make it work when the pack is empty
int dummy[]{0, (print_one<Args>::run(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};

// or, if your compiler doesn't support uniform initialization
int dummy[] = {0, (print_one<Args>::run(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};

// or, calling a dummy function
template<typename... Args> void dummy(Args...) {}
dummy((print_one<Args>::run(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...);

// or, constructing a temporary dummy object
struct dummy { dummy(std::initializer_list<int>) {} };
dummy{(print_one<Args>::run(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};

// or, constructing a temporary initializer list
std::initializer_list<int>{(print_one<Args>::run(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};
```

Note the use of the comma operator to turn the `void` return of `print_one` into a value suitable to place in an argument list or initializer expression.

The initializer-list forms are preferred to the function call forms, as they are (supposed to be) ordered LTR which function call arguments are not.

The forms where a parameter pack expansion can occur are covered by 14.5.3 [temp.variadic]:

> 4 - [...] Pack expansions can occur in the following contexts:
>
> - [...]

Your original code is illegal because although textually it might appear that it should produce a statement consisting of a number of comma-operator expressions, that is not a context allowed by 14.5.3:4.

Comment: Can you elaborate? You write about an "allowed construct". Why is my code not allowed?

Comment: Nice. Especially the trick with `,0`. But **why** doesn't it work the way I did it?

Comment: @marton78 standard reference added above.

Comment: Another good way might be `auto dummy = [](...){};`, which would be usable local to a function, as opposed to a full-blown function template. Or even just a local struct if you don't have access to lambdas (which compiler doesn't...): `struct { void operator()(...){} } dummy;`.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the array tricks fail when the pack expansion expand to nothing, since zero-size arrays are not valid.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb good point; prepending a 0 to the array initializer pack fixes it (above).

Comment: Nice catch, **litb**. Is there any advantage to using function calls over arrays? Undefined order of evaluation is a no-go, at least in my application. Also, a full solution should include casting `dummy` to `void` to silence the unused variable warning.

Comment: could also avoid named array by using cast `(char []) {0, (func(args), 0)...};`

Comment: Your suggestion to put eclipse(...) inside parenthese doesn't compile at all. The easiest fix is using "comma operator":  (print_one<Args>::run(std::forward<Args>(args)),...);

Answer (score 5):

The standard dictates where pack expansion is allowed:

`§14.5.3 [temp.variadic] p4`

> [...] Pack expansions can occur in the following contexts:
>
> - In a function parameter pack (8.3.5); the pattern is the *parameter-declaration* without the ellipsis.
> - In a template parameter pack that is a pack expansion (14.1):
>
>   - if the template parameter pack is a *parameter-declaration*; the pattern is the *parameter-declaration* without the ellipsis;
>   - if the template parameter pack is a *type-parameter* with a *template-parameter-list*; the pattern is the corresponding *type-parameter* without the ellipsis.
> - In an *initializer-list* (8.5); the pattern is an *initializer-clause*.
> - In a *base-specifier-list* (Clause 10); the pattern is a *base-specifier*.
> - In a *mem-initializer-list* (12.6.2); the pattern is a *mem-initializer*.
> - In a *template-argument-list* (14.3); the pattern is a *template-argument*.
> - In a *dynamic-exception-specification* (15.4); the pattern is a *type-id*.
> - In an *attribute-list* (7.6.1); the pattern is an *attribute*.
> - In an *alignment-specifier* (7.6.2); the pattern is the *alignment-specifier* without the ellipsis.
> - In a *capture-list* (5.1.2); the pattern is a *capture*.
> - In a `sizeof...` expression (5.3.3); the pattern is an identifier.

So basically, as a top-level statement, expansion is not allowed. The rationale behind this? No idea. Most likely they only picked contexts where a seperating comma (`,`) is part of the grammar; anywhere else you might pick overloaded `operator,` if user-defined types are involved and get in trouble.