# most elegant variadic functor

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, variadic-functions

Suppose we have two sorts of classes

- an input class `Input`

  - defines a type `result_type`
  - defines `set(result_type)`
- an output class `Output`

  - defines a type `result_type`
  - defines `result_type get() const`
  - has a number of `Input` classes as member variables, on which its output depends

Given an output class and several input classes (arbitrary number), consider the following procedure:

- loop over each input class and call `set()` with an appropriate value (defined beforehand)
- call the `get()` on the ouput class and collect the result.

This procedure can be seen as a call to a function taking the input's values as arguments an returning the output value.

**Write the functor that constructs such a variadic function in the general case.**

Constraints are: C++ (most likely C++11), arbitrary number of input classes of possibly different `Input::result_type`s. Note that `Input::result_type` is not necessarily related to `Output::result_type`. Aim should first be efficiency, but there's a big bonus if the code is elegant and readable.

*Details*: For those who wonder how `Output` is related to `Input`, one could imagine that `Input` has a `result_type get() const` method as well, which returns whatever you provided via `set()`. `Output` then has a constructor that takes various `Input`s, and stores them (or their reference) as member variables. `Output::get()` then does some math by using the return values of its input's `get()` methods, and returns some result of type `Output::result_type`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, others welcome

```
#include <functional>

template <class Output, class... Inputs>
std::function<typename Output::result_type(typename Inputs::result_type...)>
make_function(const Output& output, Inputs&... inputs) {
  return[&](typename Inputs::result_type... input_vals) {
    int dummy[]{0, (inputs.set(input_vals),0)...};
    return output.get();
  };
}
```

the `int dummy[]` line is due to @ecatmur (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515637/958110)

Comment: I'm not shy about admitting I'm utterly lost how the Output class *receives* the input instance(s) for member initialization prior to execution and establishing the final `.get()`. I see the expansion of the inputs in the dummy array, but nowhere are they married to `output`, nor could they be since `output` is `const`.  That said, the problem is interesting none-the-less. But note, the request is "Write the functor"; you wrote a *function*.

Comment: I will add a comment in the question describing this link. For me, a functor is a functional, e.g. a higher-level function, a function that works on function space. I might be wrong.

Comment: @yannick: There are other meanings in other domains.  In C++, though, a functor is strictly an object that implements `operator()()` so it can quack like a function.