# variadic template unpacking arguments to typename

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to unpack the parameter pack in `func` (see line A), but it doesnt work.  How can I unpack inside func< > or modify Line A only?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func()
{
   cerr << "EMPTY" << endl;
}

template <class A, class ...B> void func()
{
   cerr << "A: "  << endl;
   func<B... >(); // line A
}


int main(void)
{
   func<int,int>();
   return 0;
}
```

An expected output :

```
A:
A:
```

edited:
all of answers are very good. thanks alot

Comment: Not stackoverflow...infinite loop.

Comment: i know there is a problem in Line A . do you know how to fix?

Comment: When do you expect to get "EMPTY"?

Comment: i was going to use func() to stop the loop. it seems it doesnt work as i expected

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes it's easier to unpack everything at once, instead of recursively. If you simply want a parameter pack for_each, you can use a variant of [the braced-init-list expansion trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515637/923854) ([Live demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1fcef82203bf70f)):

```
template <class A>
void process_one_type() {
    cerr << typeid(A).name() << ' ';
}

template <class ...B> void func()
{
    int _[] = {0, (process_one_type<B>(), 0)...};
    (void)_;
    cerr << '\n';
}
```

Comment: how to understand this statement ? (void)_; . it is too fancy for me

Comment: @cppython It's casting the variable `_` to the type `void`, a statement expression that generates no code and typically only has the effect of telling the compiler not to warn about `_` being unused. This is necessary since the array `_` is used only for the side effects of its initialization.

Comment: please restore your original post. I am studying your first template function :)

Comment: @cppython You can see it develop in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21194071/revisions), right up until I decided that it needed to die.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need (void)_; I removed it. it works as before.

Comment: @cppython It suppresses compiler warnings about `_` being unused.

Comment: It could also be simplified to just `(char []) {(process_one_type<B>(), 0)...};`

Comment: (may want to include 0 element though)

Comment: @dinvlad `(char[]){ .... }` is the syntax for a C99 compound literal of type `char[]`. It's not valid C++ syntax.

Comment: Ok, it's probably good style to adhere to the strict standard. In case full portability is not required though, it can still be used if supported by the compiler (e.g. GCC) and built without '-pedantic'.

Answer (score 10):

By using `func<B... >();` you are implying that `func` is a function template, but your previously defined `func()` is not.

You need to define a `func()` template that accepts *zero* template arguments. Here's a working example (on g++ 4.8.1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func()
{
   cerr << "EMPTY" << endl;
}

template <class ... B>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(B) == 0>::type func()
{
}

template <class A, class ...B> void func()
{
   cerr << "A: "  << endl;
   func<B... >(); // line A
}


int main(void)
{
   func();           // This outputs EMPTY
   func<int,int>();  // This will not output EMPTY
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is the answer i am looking for but i still dont understand how it works.

Comment: Q1. typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(B) == 0>::type. this is the first time, i saw something between template<> and function name. what is that?

Comment: It's the return type. I'm sure you have seen it before :-)

Comment: @cppython: It a SFINAE trick. If `sizeof...(B)` is `true`, `enable_if::type` will be `void`. Otherwise, `enable_if` will not have any member named `type`, and template argument substitution will fail.

Comment: @cppython just search for 'C++ variadic templates', for 'c++ sfinae' and C++ 'enable_if'

Comment: Q2. why can't I  use template<> void func() to replace your  template<class ...B> part?

Comment: @cppython: Template cannot have an empty parameter list. And partial specialization is not available for function templates.

Comment: i just try to put template<> void func(){} before your main function. it works. it seems it did replace the template<class ...B> function. why?

Comment: @cppython: Did you remove the `<class...B>` function template? A `template<>` with nothing in the parameter list will be considered as a specialization. It will not compile if there's no corresponding template.

Comment: Q3. after reading more about template, May I say that the template<> void func() is explicit specialization of template<class ...B> xxx with template argument deducted?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
template <class A> void func()
{
    cerr << "A: " << endl;
}

template <class A, class B, class ...C> void func()
{
    cerr << "A: " << endl;
    func<B, C...>(); // line A
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider what the invocation of the recursive call `func<B...>();` looks like when `B...` is empty. It's calling `func<>();` but the definition of your attempted base case `func()` is not a template function, ie. you can't call it via `func<>();`

Since we don't have partial specialization for function templates yet, (hopefully it will be supported soon) one way to do it is to use a class template to do the partial specialization and use the function to simply delegate the work to the class template.

```
#include <iostream>

/* Forward declaration. */
template <typename... T>
struct FuncImpl;

/* Base case. */
template <>
struct FuncImpl<> {

  void operator()() const {
    std::cout << "Base case" << std::endl;
  }

};  // FuncImpl<>

/* Recursive case. */
template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct FuncImpl<First, Rest...> {

  void operator()() const {
    std::cout << "Recursive case" << std::endl;
    FuncImpl<Rest...>()();
  }

};  // FuncImpl<First, Rest...>

/* Delegate function. */
template <typename... T>
void Func() {
  FuncImpl<T...>()();
}

int main() {
  Func<>();
  Func<int, double>();
}
```

Personally I think this solution is cleaner than other solutions such as tagged dispatching or SFINAE, despite the cruft around `operator()`s.